# returning array to spill into next cell

Tags: arrays, syntax, range, user-defined-functions

If I have a range of cells as input data, say from A1 to G1, all containing numbers. How would I get the function to return a number to H1 and I1... I want it to return an array in H1, spilling into I1. It must be a UDF, these cells are just an example.

```
Function test(t As Range) As Variant
Set a = t(3)+2
Set b = t(4)+3
test = (a,b)
End Function
```